# Durable Streaming Limit reached in Error

Tags: streaming-api

3 times in the past 3 months our data collectors in StreamSets have received a message that "Organization total events daily limit exceeded". Which would indicate that we have used 1M events in 24 hours.

I can also watch the event consumption change from the Rest API's limits method and it does report that we used 1M.

But we didn't. From all our metrics, we can see that we used our typical load of ~100K. Nevertheless, the error persists for a few hours as the rolling limit catches up.

I've tried to work with Support on this issue, but they are too slow to respond while it's happening and afterwards claim that they do not see the error in the logs, or that I'm providing insufficient details about the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem was replays. Our data collector kept requesting the same replay ID and generating thousands of events. This would then run us up to the limit and triggering the data collector to try harder to replay missed events.

Comment: So what was the *resolution*?

Comment: How did you discover that? Did Salesforce support help?